# How to remove animation on revert of jQuery UI draggable?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I tried Googling and couldn't find this, but I imagine it is a fairly simple task. I am trying to get rid of the revert animation (N.B. I want to keep the revert action, just want to remove the animation of it reverting) when you drop from the left side to the right side in this example : http://jsfiddle.net/2fsVZ/

Here is the long and short of what I am looking for:

Below is the JavaScript I am working with - how do I tell it to not animate the revert?

```
  $( ".before .left-side>div" ).draggable({ revert: true});
```

Comment: Please post a portion of your code here in addition to the jsfiddle link. This way if the jsfiddle link is lost the question is still helpful to others.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You just need to set the revertDuration to 0.

```
$( ".before .left-side>div" ).draggable({
    revert: true,
    revertDuration: 0
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2fsVZ/2/

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Draggable#option-revertDuration

Comment: I knew it was something simple!! Thanks!!